# How to use map operator in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to `fetch` mutual friends and put those in mutual friends' property.
but, in users object of `res.send()` function, it doesn't contain mutual friends property

```
   router.get('/friends', auth, async (req, res) => {
   try {
      let users = await User.find({
         friends: req.user._id
      })
      users.map((user) => {
         let userAltered = {
            ...user.toObject()
         }
         userAltered.userImage = userAltered.userImageThumbnail;
         delete userAltered.userImageThumbnail;
         userAltered.mutualFriends = [];
         userAltered.friends.forEach((friend) => {
            if (req.user.friends.findIndex((myFriend) => {
                  return friend.toString() == myFriend.toString()
               }) > 0) {
               userAltered.mutualFriends.push(friend);
            }
         })
         return userAltered;
      })
      res.send({
         users,
         loggedInUserId: req.user.id
      });
   } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send(e);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `users` object returned by the query will be in an immutable state. You need to convert it into a javascript object first. Currently, only the objects inside the `users` are converted to objects, Since the `users` list itself is immutable the changes will not be applied to it

In your case, you need to perform this first

```js
const result = users.map(u => u.toObject());
```

```js
router.get("/friends", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let users = await User.find({
      friends: req.user._id,
    });
    const result = users.map((u) => u.toObject());
    result.map((user) => {
      user.userImage = user.userImageThumbnail;
      delete user.userImageThumbnail;
      user.mutualFriends = [];
      user.friends.forEach((friend) => {
        if (
          req.user.friends.findIndex((myFriend) => {
            return friend.toString() == myFriend.toString();
          }) > 0
        ) {
            user.mutualFriends.push(friend);
        }
      });
      return user;
    });
    res.send({
      result, // returning result object
      loggedInUserId: req.user.id,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: @PrashantZende Just to get a clear picture, so currently you are first creating a `result` object from the query response as mentioned in the answer and then using the `map` on the `result` again to add new key-value pair to each element inside the `result` right?

Comment: you are partiall correct. I am not adding new key value pairs. instead altering existing ones by iterating them through map operator

Comment: I have updated the answer, Is your current implementation like this?